# C# Arcobjects 10.3: Change the source version on a layer file

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.3

I'm using arcobjects (C#) to load my layers to the table of contents, and I need to update the data source to change the version.

The layer file is set to the correct source at the DEFAULT version. When a 'user' opens the MXD, i need to update the version just before it loads.

I'm not sure where to start with this. 
Here is the loading code:

```
 var groupL = new GroupLayer();
 groupL.Name = ALayerName;

 var fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(alayerDir, FileFilter).ToList();

 fileEntries.ForEach(delegate(string path)
 {
    var layer = ActiveView.OpenLyrFromFile(path);
    groupL.Add(layer);
 });
 return groupL;
```

So what to i need to cast 'layer' to in order to give the new version name and then restart the connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I recall, you need to listen to `IDocumentEvents`.

When `OpenDocument` fires cast the IMxDocument to `IDocumentDatasets`.  For  each `IDatasetLayer2` in `IDocumentDatasets.Datasets`:

Cast IDatasetLayer2.DataSourceName to IDataSetName.

Get (by value) `IDatasetName.WorkspaceName`. 
Get (by value) the propertyset from `IWorkspaceName.ConnectionProperties`.

Change the "VERSION" property in the propertyset to whatever version you want.

Assign the property set back to `IWorkspaceName.ConnectionProperties`.

Assign the workspacename back to `IDatasetName.WorkspaceName`,

Assign the datasetname back to `IDatasetLayer2.DatasourceName`.

Alternatively, you might want to call `IDatasetLayer2.Connect`, passing the modified datasetname.

Comment: I changed it a bit, but creating the propertyset dynamically (with the version set) and create a new sde. I then change the layer workspace to the new SDE.